# Just creating a new Xamarin Forms Content Page Xaml makes the project uncompilable as ContentPageViewModel is uknown

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Adding this to my PCL, the code behind file has this line:

```
BindingContext = new ContentPageViewModel();
```

In the constructor. The compiler does not know about ContentPageViewModel.

How is it possible that things break this fast? Am I not supposed to use ContentPages with a Xamarin Forms app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that this is a bug in the current templates. Check the bug on the Xamarin Bugzilla [here](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=53104).

You can work around it by implementing the actual ViewModel yourself, or just removing the line if you do not wish to use it.

Comment: So it has been known for at least 3 weeks that a template is bugged straight out of the box?

Comment: It seems so! Just the release cycle isn't that fast to catch up with it probably. It isn't that big of a deal, just remove the line for now. If it is the answer you have been looking for, please mark it as an answer :)

Answer (score 3):

The name of my file was GreetPage.xaml.cs. 
Just substitute out 'ContactPage' for the name of your file.

[image]